# Some text missing in jar executed file

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans

After run my jar file some text are missing its appear,

Eg: in my gui have "admin" but in jar file its appear only "admi"

What is the reason for that?
Thank you for answer

Answer (score 0):

JAR actually is a ZIP file. So it content can not match original code.

Comment: But how can i export my project as a application